# Java Combat Simulator - I want to simulate 1000 fights, to keep track how many times the hero wins/loses

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm really a newbie in java world and I'm studying right now, IFs/FORs/WHILEs and so on. To keep interest in the subject I let my nerd side go free :)

I want to simulate 1000 fights, between a Hero and a Goblin. Both have their stats and d20 throw to determine if they hit ((d20+bonus)> enemy armor). If they hit, they deal the related dmg and keep exchanging blasts until one of the two is dead.
Everytime Goblin HPs drop below 0, the Hero score a 'win', in the opposite case he scores a 'defeat'.

The simulation interrupts when the cycle repeated itself for 1000 plays, showing how many wins and defeats the hero had.

This is my failing code.It keeps on counting infinitely the number of wins, without resetting the Goblin HPs and the Hero HPs, also not counting the defeats number.
Can someone use simple constructs to help me understanding where I go wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Random2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int wins = 0, defeats = 0;
        int hpHero = 20, armorHero = 8, dmgHero = 4, bonusHero = 1;
        int hpGoblin = 10, armorGoblin = 5, dmgGoblin = 3, bonusGoblin = 1;

        for (int played = 0; played <= 1000; played++) {

            while (hpHero > 0 || hpGoblin > 0) {
                int d20Hero = rand.nextInt(19);
                d20Hero += 1;

                if ((bonusHero + d20Hero) > armorGoblin) {
                    System.out.println("You hit the goblin with a die result of " + (bonusHero + d20Hero));
                    hpGoblin -= dmgHero;
                    System.out.println("HP Goblin: " + hpGoblin);
                    if (hpGoblin > 0) {
                        int d20Goblin = rand.nextInt(19);
                        d20Goblin += 1;

                        if ((bonusGoblin + d20Goblin) > armorHero) {
                            System.out.println("Goblin hit the human with a die result of " + (bonusGoblin + d20Goblin));
                            hpHero -= dmgGoblin;
                            System.out.println("HP Hero: " + hpHero);

                            if (hpHero < 1) {
                                defeats++;
                                System.out.println("Defeats are: " + defeats);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        wins++;
                        System.out.println("Wins are: " + wins);
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You claim that the code is "failing", but *how* is it "failing"? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to include more details. And while editing your question, please make sure that the code is consistently indented, so it's easier to follow what it does.

Comment: As far as I see, maybe you'll have to initiate the health of your heroes IN the for loop. And change the while condition, because if your heroe win I supposed the life of your goblin is 0 ... so a && instead of the || could be nice...

Comment: Thank you Mohicane,now it works!

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can say with relative certainty is that your program seems to be lacking a mechanism for restoring `hpHero` and `hpGoblin` inbetween each fight.
You could do this as follows.

```
    for (int played = 0; played <= 1000; played++) {
        hpHero = 20;
        hpGoblin = 10;
        while (hpHero > 0 || hpGoblin > 0) {
```

I think there may be more problems than this, however.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your code as little as possible, however I would recommend taking some time and rethinking it because it is a little bit over complicated.

The two things I noticed are

- you never reset the HP of the combatants
- the goblin's attack depends on the hero's attack (nested if means goblin won't attack unless the hero has a successful attack)

Here is the updated version

```
public class Random2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();

    int wins = 0, defeats = 0;
    int armorHero = 8, dmgHero = 4, bonusHero = 1;
    int armorGoblin = 5, dmgGoblin = 3, bonusGoblin = 1;

    // fight 1000 times
    for (int played = 0; played <= 1000; played++) {
      // start with full stats after each fight
      int hpHero = 20;
      int hpGoblin = 10;

      // while both combatants are still alive
      while (hpHero > 0 || hpGoblin > 0) {
        // hero rolls
        int d20Hero = rand.nextInt(19);
        d20Hero += 1;
        // if hero can hit then do the dmg
        if ((bonusHero + d20Hero) > armorGoblin) {
          System.out.println("You hit the goblin with a die result of " + (bonusHero + d20Hero));
          hpGoblin -= dmgHero;
          System.out.println("HP Goblin: " + hpGoblin);
        }

        // if the goblin is still alive then it rolls
        if (hpGoblin > 0) {
          int d20Goblin = rand.nextInt(19);
          d20Goblin += 1;

          // if the goblin can hit then do the dmg
          if ((bonusGoblin + d20Goblin) > armorHero) {
            System.out.println("Goblin hit the human with a die result of " + (bonusGoblin + d20Goblin));
            hpHero -= dmgGoblin;
            System.out.println("HP Hero: " + hpHero);

            // if hero died then count defeat
            if (hpHero < 1) {
              defeats++;
              System.out.println("Defeats are: " + defeats);
            }
          }
        } else { // if goblin did not survive then count a win for the hero
          wins++;
          System.out.println("Wins are: " + wins);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```